# Time limit exceeds error in spoj next palindrome

Tags: java, time

I am trying to resolve next palindrome problem in SPOJ. I am getting Time limit exceeded error in my Java code below.

"A positive integer is called a palindrome if its representation in the decimal system is the same when read from left to right and from right to left. For a given positive integer K of not more than 1000000 digits, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than K to output. Numbers are always displayed without leading zeros."

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nextpalindrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Scanner in =new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=in.nextInt();

        for (int i=1;i<=t;i++)
        {
            BigInteger bi = in.nextBigInteger();    
            String str=bi.toString();
            String str1=new String();
            String str2=new String();
            String str3=new String();
            String str4=new String();
            int l=str.length();
            int comp=0;
            if (l==2)
            {
                str1=str.substring(0,1);
                str2=str.substring(1,2);

                if (Integer.parseInt(str1)>Integer.parseInt(str2))
                str1=str1.concat(str1); 
                else if (Integer.parseInt(str2)>Integer.parseInt(str1))
                {
                str2=str2.concat(str2);             
                str1=str2;
                }
                else if (Integer.parseInt(str1)==Integer.parseInt(str2))
                {
                    int x=Integer.parseInt(str1)+1;
                    str1=Integer.toString(x);
                    str1=str1.concat(str1); 
                    }
            }

            if (l%2>0)
            {
                str1=str.substring(0,l/2);
                str2=str.substring((l/2)+1,l);
                str3 =str.substring(l/2,(l/2)+1);
                str4=new StringBuffer(str1).reverse().toString();
                BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger(str1);
                BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(str2);

                comp= bi1.compareTo(bi2);

                int mid=Integer.parseInt(str3);
                if (comp==-1)
                {
                mid+=1;
                String str5=Integer.toString(mid);
                str1=str1.concat(str5);
                str1=str1.concat(str4);
                }
                else if (comp==1)
                {
                String str5=Integer.toString(mid);
                str1=str1.concat(str5);
                str1=str1.concat(str4);
                }
                else if (comp==0)
                {
                    mid+=1;
                String str5=Integer.toString(mid);
                str1=str1.concat(str5);
                str1=str1.concat(str4);
                }
            }
            if ((l>2)&&(l%2==0))
            {
                str1=str.substring(0,l/2);
                str2=str.substring(l/2,l);

                BigInteger bi1 = new BigInteger(str1);
                BigInteger bi2 = new BigInteger(str2);
                BigInteger bi3=new BigInteger("1");
                comp= bi1.compareTo(bi2);
                if (comp==-1)
                {
                bi1=bi1.add(bi3);
                str1=bi1.toString();
                str4=new StringBuffer(str1).reverse().toString();
                str1=str1.concat(str4);
                }
                else if ((comp==1)||(comp==0))
                {
               str4=new StringBuffer(str1).reverse().toString();
                str1=str1.concat(str4);
                }
            }



        System.out.println(str1);

        }

        in.close();     

    }

}
```

Comment: might want to [edit] your question to include a [java] tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're wanting to find the smallest palindrome larger than K, consider these rules and logic:

- In order for the smallest palindrome to be larger than K, you have to use all of the digits. (i.e. 1122 => 1221 would be the answer).
- An odd length number can only have **ONE** digit with a frequency of one, this number would be the center digit, the other digits must have an even frequency (i.e. 11121 => 11211 would be the answer).  Otherwise, you cannot create a palindrome.
- With an even length number, all the digits must have an even frequency (Example, see bullet one).  Otherwise, you cannot create a palindrome.

I would start with getting the frequency of each digit and go from there.

Hope this helps.